# How to set a light popup theme?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-styles

My `PopupWindow` requires a light theme, so I am trying to change it using `ContextThemeWrapper`:

```
if (R.id.action_filter == item.getItemId()) {
    View filterView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.action_filter);
    assert  filterView != null;
    Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(filterView.getContext(),
            R.style.ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_ActionBar);
    FilterWindow menu = new FilterWindow(context); //PopupWindow
    menu.showAsDropDown(filterView, 0, -filterView.getHeight());
    return true;
}

private static class FilterWindow extends PopupWindow {

    FilterWindow(Context context) {
        super(context);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_filter, null);
        setContentView(view);
        setOutsideTouchable(true);
        setFocusable(true);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work... I tried different styles but my background is black always. How to set a light theme?

Answer (score 0):

After learning of a source code and AppCompat styles I got why it doesn't work. Below a working variant is:

```
if (R.id.action_filter == item.getItemId()) {
    View filterView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.action_filter);
    assert  filterView != null;
    FilterWindow menu = new FilterWindow(getContext());
    menu.showAsDropDown(filterView, 0, -filterView.getHeight());
    return true;
}

private static class FilterWindow extends PopupWindow {

    FilterWindow(Context context) {
        super(context, null, R.attr.popupMenuStyle);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_filter, null);
        setContentView(view);
        setOutsideTouchable(true);
        setFocusable(true);
    }
}
```

Of course, you also need to derive a popup theme of your `Toolbar` from `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light`.